# How to add Node.js result in my HTML project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

this is my project: http://cryptotipsitalia.sytes.net/.
I want add Ethereum value down to "Valore BTC" with Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-price.
How can I add it?

That's my code:

```js
function getValueBTC() {    <!-- chiamata API --> /




    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    var output;

    console.log(url);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        output = this.responseText;
                        var obj = JSON.parse(output);
                        var rightValue = (obj.bpi.EUR.rate).substring(0,obj.bpi.EUR.rate.length-2); /* eliminazione ultime due cifre */
                        document.getElementById("cellaValoreBTC").innerHTML= obj.bpi.EUR.symbol + " " + rightValue;

                        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    xmlhttp.send();

}


    let price = require('crypto-price');

    price.getCryptoPrice('EUR', 'ETH').then(obj => {
        console.log(obj.price); // It will print ETH rate per BTC
        document.getElementById("cellaValoreETH").innerHTML = obj.price;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

```html
table><tr><td width="75%">VALORE BTC:</td></tr><tr id="cellaValoreBTC" width="75%"></tr><tr><td width="75%">VALORE ETH:</td></tr><tr id="cellaValoreETH" width="75%"></table>
```

Why "document.getElementById("cellaValoreBTC").innerHTML = obj.price;" doesnt' work?
How can I add obj.price in my HTML code?

Thanks

Comment: From the usage of DOM api I assume that its a client side script. You have a require statement in middle of client side script
`let price = require('crypto-price');`

Comment: It's there in the script

Comment: typically, packages are used on the server side and not on client side